# jquery & SEO - using methods to hide content via js

Tags: jquery, seo

we currently have a number of clients that we build sites for and they constantly request to have the entire homepage listed as a jpeg (majority of them are fashion clients)...

I know that with SEO you are not allowed to disguise the page in anyway, however i am wondering if anyone knows if its OK to do the following.

1. Create all the content within the page
2. create articles within the page that is relevent to the pages image content
3. Hide all the text within the page using $("divid").hide(); or $("#divid").remove()

As it is javascript, im wondering what sort of impact it will have on a page when submitted to google.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be the expert? You should tell your clients not to do it, for various reasons (and one very good reason is the one John Conde just answered below).

Answer (score 2):

Serving up different content to search engines, regardless of method or technique, is called cloaking and is against their terms of service. What you are trying to do would be considered cloaking would result in your client's site ultimately getting banned.

Comment: so its actually quite easy. 1. apply the content into a div that is removed onload, then also apply it into a noscript tag so that google recognizes the content...